# Xamarin the use of SQLite component. Cant view saved items on the screen

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have developed my first ToDo app by adding SQLite component but I am having problems viewing saved tasks on the screen. I am not sure if I am creating the database file correctly.I think I messed up here:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{ 
  SQLiteConnection conn ;

  public TaskViewModel ()
  {
    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); 
    conn = new SQLiteConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "tasks.db"));
    conn.CreateTable<Task> ();
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks correct.  You should probably check for the existence of "tasks.db" before you CreateTable(), otherwise you may overwrite existing data.  I can't recall how SQLite handles this.

Comment: Since I am a newbie on this ,I have created tasks.db on as new access file and copied to one of the folders in the project main folder. Could you tell me what exactly 3.and 4. code line does ?

Comment: How do i check tasks.db ?

Comment: if (!File.Exists(folder)) { // file does not exist, create it }

Answer (score 1):

Your connection and file creation seems ok, but you might have problems on updating your view. Take a look on how you are binding the data to the view and the events that you use to update it.

Remember to always use `Open` and `Close` on SQL connections when using them.

Take a look on a class I use to start the data binding process:

```
class Repository
{
    public const string db_file = "tasks.db3";
    public static string db_path = Path.Combine (System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), db_file);

    public static SqliteConnection GetConnection ()
    {
        bool exists = File.Exists (db_path);

        if (!exists)
            SqliteConnection.CreateFile (db_path);

        var conn = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + db_path);
        if (!exists)
            CreateDatabase (conn);

        return conn;
    }

    public static Person Task { get; set; }

    private static void CreateDatabase (SqliteConnection conn)
    {
        var sql = @"CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    Name VARCHAR(250),
    Description VARCHAR(250),
    Enabled BOOLEAN,
    Timestamp DATETIME
    );";

        conn.Open ();

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand ()) {
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();
        }

        conn.Close ();
    }
}
```